# React Native: Refresh component on click button

Tags: react-native

I tried to create a chat in my application. Messages are stored in a server and I comunicate with it with an API. I tried to make it real time chat so I used `componentDidUpdate` `shouldComponentUpdate` method (`componentDidUpdate` and `componentwillupdate` too) but there is a warning that appears telling me that make my application very weak... in any case I can't do it like this.

I want suggestions to be able to display the message when the user click on the send button and how can I have a notification of receipt of new messages

Comment: Hi, could you please post the message you are getting please? and some sample code would also be great

Comment: I have this warning when I add an 'update' method. Warning: Can't perform a Reat state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application..... I will put some code in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding extraData flatlist prop:

```
      <FlatList
        style={Styles.flatlist}
        data={this.state.msg.Conversation}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.datetime.toString()}
        extraData={this.state} //this prop
        renderItem={({item}) => <MsgR msg={item}/>}
        inverted= {-1}
      />
```

and when I click the send button, I re-call `getMsgFromApi()` method:

```
onPressSend() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_STORED)
      .then(userIdStore => {
              this.setState({ userId: userIdStore});
              this.sendMsgS(this.state.userId).then(() => {
                this.setState({msgS: ''});
this method --> this.getMsgFromApi(this.state.userId).then(data => {
                  this.setState({ msg: data,});
                });
              });
      });
}
```

and it's work fine: when I click on send button, I have the message sent displayed after a few ms, it's unpleasant but it works !

Answer (score 0):

in case your server is not sending notifications on new message, you can implement polling mechanism to check server for any new message after certain small time intervals.
as long as you are fetching new messages and populating them, using redux, you will only need componentwillreceiveprops method which you can use to set state of new message array.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is probably coming from the "unsafe" (deprecated in React 17) method `componentwillupdate`. These methods (including `componentwillreceiveprops` as Firdous mentioned) shouldn't be used anymore in preference for methods such as `componentdidupdate`.

What you're looking to achieve can be done with an appropriate use of `componentdidupdate` and perhaps `getderivedstatefromprops` if needed. For instance, if you have connected your chat view (and your message text input) to redux (which should hold the messages) the `componentdidupdate` method will listen to incoming prop changes (from the onPress event for instance from your text input) and can therefore update the view with the new props (messages).

Comment: As stated by @chazza, the warning comes from the UNSAFE functions you are using and specifically the state :

React tells you that you are trying to state the state of a component that is not mounted yet ! Either use `redux` (which you shouldn't) or as pointed by @chazza & @Firdous use a combination of life-cycle methods and some sort of pooling:

1. Wait 10s, fetch messages
2. Try to state the state of new message array
3. You could also check for changes in previous message array to re-render only the part that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I provide some code to more details:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.msg !== this.state.msg) {
    this.getMsgFromApi(this.state.userId).then(data => {
      this.setState({ msg: data})
    });
  }
};
```

and to display messages when component will mount i do this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_STORED)
    .then(userIdStore => {
        this.setState({ userId: userIdStore});
        this.getMsgFromApi(this.state.userId).then(data => {
          this.setState({ msg: data})
        });
    });
};
```

all message are dislaied in a flatlist

```
    <View style={Styles.messagesContainer}>
      <FlatList
        style={Styles.flatlist}
        data={this.state.msg.Conversation}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.datetime.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => <MsgR msg={item}/>}
        inverted= {-1}
      />
    </View>
```

and I do a condition to differentiate if it is a user message or a received message because the API that handles the messages puts them like this :

```
"Conversation": [
{
"adherent": "received message",
"user": null,
"datetime":"2019-07-09
09: 42: 55"
},
{
"adherent":null,
"user":"user message",
"datetime":"2019-07-04 06: 14: 18"
}
2","user":null,"datetime":"2019-07-03 12: 34: 10"
},
]
```

display of messages according to the sender:

```
const msg = this.props.msg;
return (
    <View style={[Styles.container, msg.user===null ? Styles.right : Styles.left]}>
      <Text style={msg.user===null ? Styles.textMsgRight : Styles.textMsgLeft}>{msg.user===null ? msg.adherent : msg.user}</Text>
    </View>
);
```